Removing success message after deleting was denied
Given the fact, that this is already some years old and no perfect answer was provided:
How do I overwrite the delete_model() / delete_queryset() functions in the admin, so the success message is not shown for cases where the deletion was denied?
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if not can_delete():
            messages.error(request, "cannot delete ...")
            return
        super().delete_queryset(request, queryset)

The logic works, but I get a success AND an error message which is confusing for the user. I know I can go the long way and implement a whole custom logic, but then I would face the issue of not seeing the "are you sure ..." page? I have the same problem I show here for delete_queryset() also with the delete_model().

Context for the duplicate: The premise of this question itself is problematic, instead of overriding delete_queryset, etc. one should simply override the has_delete_permission method and the admin site will properly throw an error on its own.

This is not what I meant to ask. I want to use delete_model() and delete_queryset(), not forbid the deletion (the function can_delete() simulates that under some circumstances the user might not be allowed to delete).

You can do that with has_delete_permissions as the name suggests it is supposed to return whether the user has permissions to delete a particular object or not which is what your can_delete function is also doing. The difference here is that has_delete_permissions is automatically called by the admin site before calling delete_model() or delete_queryset() whereas your function needs to be called explicitly by you.

this is exactly what I needed, thanks. If you post it as an answer I will approve it.
